# How to Automate Maps with Selenium Java? or with Page Co-Ordinates. Pleas show me is there any other way to Automate Maps

Tags: java, selenium, automation, maps

I'm Trying to capture the Co-ordinates of Maps to do some action on Maps.

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.`path`("//button[contains(text(),'Add Tract')]"))).click(); 
Utils.scrollUp(); 
Thread.sleep(10000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("TimeZoneId"))); 
//Timezone is the area which I'm trying to capture the Co-Ordinates

Point point1 = timezone.getLocation(); 
SOP("Element's Position from left side is: "+point1.getX()+" pixels."); 
SOP("Element's Position from top is: "+point1.getY()+" pixels."); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your map has `<canvas>` tag, then try

1. To perform using Actions chains, below is an example C# code similar to Java

```
IWebElement canvas = driver.FindElement(By.Id("TimeZoneId"));
int xCo = canvas.Location.X;
int yCo = canvas.Location.Y;Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(canvas, 1 + xCo, 2 + yCo).Click().Build().Perform();
```

2. Try [OpenCV](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/html-canvas-testing-selenium-opencv-maciej-kusz)
3. If you are testing overlays on map. use [JavaScriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) and by adding [hooks](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polygons) to your code in order to perform actions in your Map.
4. Try with Sikuli (personally, I have not used this. Needs some research)